# Comparison of floating point types

Tags: c#, performance, floating-point

Are there any performance differences between

```
 float x, y;
 // Set x and y
 if(x > y)
 {
    // do something
 }
```

and

```
 float x,y;
 // Set x and y
 if(x.CompareTo(y) > 0)
 {
    // do something
 }
```

Are they doing the same thing behind the scenes or is there more to it.  I have a piece of performance critical code that does this comparison many, many times and I wanted to check that there wasn't more going on than I thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one will be a little bit faster and a lot more readable.

`x > y` compiles to an IL instruction that compares two values on the stack.

`x.CompareTo(y) > 0` compiles to a normal method call followed by a comparison, which will be a little bit slower.

Comment: @Brian - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74z9b11e(VS.95).aspx for more information on what the `CompareTo` method is doing.

Comment: The less operations the cpu has to perform the better.

Answer (score 4):

The following is a general remark, disregarding performance. You should be aware that there is a slight difference between using the operator and the `IComparable` method. They are *almost* doing the same. The difference is when both your values are `NaN` and you are checking for equality. See the following example:

```
float x = float.NaN;
float y = float.NaN;

bool resultOperator = (x == y);               // will be false
bool resultCompareTo = (x.CompareTo(y) == 0); // will be true(!)
```

The reason for this inconsistency is that the the [`IComparable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.compareto.aspx) interface requires that `x.CompareTo(x)` returns zero.